# Get Windows session-id

Tags: windows, session, batch-file

Is there any command or batch script which allows me to only get the session id of an user? I know about `Query Session`, but it displays more information than I need.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there is.

```
TASKLIST /FI "USERNAME EQ yourusername"
```

This will list all tasks started by yourusername. If you want to do something with these tasks, say like (killing them) you can use

```
TASKKILL /FI "USERNAME EQ yourusername"
```

but be careful, you might end up killing EXPLORER.EXE which will cause Windows to behave abnormally, so I suggest something like this

```
TASKKILL /FI "imagename eq EXCEL.EXE"
```

for more information on how to use TASKKILL and TASKLIST type

```
TASKLIST /?
TASKKILL /?
```

If you only want the PID of these tasks, then you can save the output of TASKLIST to CSV file by appending /FO to the command line then type a file name to write to like this

```
tasklist /fi "username eq 25163" /fo csv > mytasks.csv
```

This will create a CSV file that you can open using EXCEL containing all the columns you need to work with

Comment: Well Thanks for that nice describtion, but obviously you misunderstood. :) I'm not trying to get the PID or processes of an user, I'm trying to get his id (if you look at the Users tab in task manager you'll notice the session id).